# Extract image src from the whole div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am working in JavaScript. My code is:

```
<div id="myDiv" onClick="myfn()">
<img src="a.png">
<img src="b.png">
</div>
```

I want to get the source of the images and store it in the array on click of a button.
Any help ???

```
myfn() {    
  var a = new Array(); 
  var mainDivData = document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML;
  var mainDivData2 = mainDivData.getElementByTag('src');

  for(var i =0 ; i<mainDivData2.length; i ++) {
    //a[i] = mainDivData2;
    alert(a[i]);
  }
}
```

But nothing shown in the alert even alert window doesn't opened. 
Any help ???

Comment: What have you tried so far and what exactly are you having problems with? (e.g. binding a click event handler, getting a reference to the div/images, reading attributes, etc).

Comment: `mainDivData` is a *string* containing HTML, not a DOM element. Strings don't have a `getElementByTag` method (you should see an error like `TypeError: Object ... has no method 'getElementByTag'`), neither does such a DOM method exist (it's `getElementsByTagName` (note the `s`)). Neither are there any elements with tag `src`, it is an *attribute* of the image elements (which have the tag `img`). Learn more about DOM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM.

Comment: @FelixKling: hence his question on SO. He was struggling with this (apparently) but couldn't get his head around it...

Comment: @Robert: Just explaining what's wrong ;) Getting a solution to the problem is only one part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pure JavaScript solution:

```
var imgs = document.getElementById("myDiv").getElementsByTagName("img"),
    arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    arr.push(imgs[i].src);
}

console.log(arr);
```

jQuery solution:

```
var arr = $("#myDiv img").map(function() {
    return this.src;
}).get();

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: +1 for the use of `.get()` without arguments. I never thought of using it as a jQuery set replacer to the underlying array. I've used jQuery for so many years but usually only saw the `.get(0)`, which is of course equivalent to `[0]`.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Yes, `map()` method returns just sort of array, not the *pure* one (practically, an array wrapped into jQuery object). To extract the array itself `get()` method must be applied. We can find the information about it in [docs](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Comment: well... this *sort of array* has a name: **jQuery set**. ;) Just so you know. And I know what `get()` does. I've just never used (or seen it being used) it without arguments. And that's what earned you the +1... No need for an explanation.

Comment: Can i access the style tag after getting the src tag ??

Comment: @BurhanMughal Yes, you can. Why not?

Comment: I want to select the image with style ="border: 2px solid red" how can i do this

Comment: Well that's great .. How ??

Comment: will you please post another answer ??

Comment: @BurhanMughal That's an absolutely different question. And the answer will be also different. It's not a good idea to mix different questions in one.

Comment: Ok should i ask another one ?? or can carry this in chat window ?

Comment: @BurhanMughal I believe, you may ask another question.